# declarative pipeline function for git checkout

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, git-checkout, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I have a jenkinsfile that I try to execute using shared libraries.
my function (for now work as in line function) is:

```
def gitCheckout(gitUrl, creadencialsId = "", branch, scm){
    script {
        echo "inside"
        checkout (
            poll:false,
            scm: [
                $class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: "${branch}"]], 
                extensions: scm.extensions,
                submoduleCfg: [],
                userRemoteConfigs: [[refspec: "+refs/heads/${branch}:refs/remotes/origin/${branch}", url: "${gitUrl}", credentialsId: "${credentialsId}"]]
            ]
        )
    }
}
```

and I'm trying to pass inside the array of the scm.extensions so I can modify it before using it, for now what I'm trying is:

```
stage('Get Sources') {
    steps {
        script {
            echo "before extensions"
            scm.extensions = [[$class: 'CloneOption', noTags: true, reference: '', shallow: false], [$class: 'DisableRemotePoll']]
            echo "before git checkout"
            gitCheckout("${gitUrl}", "SSH-for-git", "${params.branch}", scm)
        }
    }
}
```

but no luck!
I can't find anywhere the way to use correctly the scm object.
I tried things like

```
scm.extensions.add([[$class: 'CloneOption', noTags: true, reference: '', shallow: false], [$class: 'DisableRemotePoll']])

scm.extensions += [[$class: 'CloneOption', noTags: true, reference: '', shallow: false]] + [[$class: 'DisableRemotePoll']]
```

etc. still no luck